# Remove text from UITextView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to make a `UITextView` with some text and one button when user select this button hide the text word by word from `UITextView` after a fix timing. How can I do this?[image]

[image: after some words remove one by one]

In 1st image all words are present but in 2nd screen after some time words are erase one by one for this i am using a timer and call method

```
 firststring = myArray[countNew];
 NSRange range=[self.textView.text rangeOfString:firststring];
  [stringWithRTFAttributes addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} range:range];
  [self.textView setAttributedText:stringWithRTFAttributes];
  countNew++;
 if(countNew>=count)
 {
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"Timer Stops");
 }
```

where count is array which store total words and countNew is integer variable.

Comment: How can i use it? please explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this issue call the go method with a timer,this is my code

```
-(void)go
{
firststring = myArray[countNew];
 NSInteger location = location1;
 NSInteger index = index1;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, [[myArray objectAtIndex:countNew] length]);
NSLog(@"my range is %@  firstString %@", NSStringFromRange(range) ,firststring);
[stringWithRTFAttributes addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:range];
[_textView setAttributedText:stringWithRTFAttributes];
[_textView setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
location1 = [[myArray objectAtIndex:countNew] length] +location +1;
index1 = index++;
countNew++;
if(countNew>=[myArray count])
 {
    [timer invalidate];

 }

}
```

Here location1, index1 are two long int type data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` and change text colour of particular words to `clearColor` or `backgroundColor`. `NSTimer` is a good approach for this.

As an example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Dummy String" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];
[string addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor clearColor]} range:{range of substring}];
```

And for multiple occurrences of a substring, you can have that kind of approach:

```
NSString *string = @"Dummy String";
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
...  //within your scheduled/for loop:
static NSInteger location = 0;
static NSInteger index = 0;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(location, [[words objectAtIndex:index] length]);
location += [[words objectAtIndex:index] length];
index++;
```

Comment: I am using this , it work for only first time words if word come 2 times then it not work

Comment: Then your question is merely a "how to split a sentence into words?" question. I made an edit.

Comment: @MertBuran please check my answer , with this i can remove text from textview after a fix time but i also want that if my text is large the height of textview then automatically textview become scroll and show the text, please tell me something ??

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you. Maybe you can use scrollRangeToVisible function of UITextView

Comment: Yes actually the textview height is only 100. and if textview.text is large then maximum part of text hidden if user scroll it then it show but i want when text become remove from textview then it automatically show the hidden text like scrollRangeToVisible, i have use this method but text show only 1 line in bottom of textview  so any other idea or how can i set the range for  remaining text which not shown in textview due to its height?